# Haskell multiplication - why does 4.5 * 7.65 given the incorrect result of 34.425000000000004?

Tags: haskell, multiplication

I've been learning some Haskell and I'm really confused by this behaviour when multiplying 4.5 * 7.65 in the console the result given is 34.425000000000004 and not the correct answer of 34.425. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

[Screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0ny7.png)

Thanks

Comment: If you want precise arithmetic, hoogle for `Rational` and `Scientific`.

Comment: `4.5 * 7.65 :: Float` prints its result as `34.425`. :)

Comment: The part `:: Float` coerces the result to type Float

Comment: @FrancisKing One must be careful about the word "coerce". Certainly in this use at least, it doesn't align with the way that word is used in most other languages. There is no other type than `Float` that is used in intermediate calculations, then converted; the calculation is just done on `Float`s from the get-go.